How to get multiple hosts output in one file in Ansible playbook?
I have a requirement to collect all my service running status on multiple hosts and get it in one output file.
- name: To check status of services running
  hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: "Check backup service"
      shell:|
         if ps -ef | grep 'netbackup' | grep =v grep > /dev/null; then
                echo ' backup service running'
         else
                echo ' backup service not running'
         fi
      ignore_errors: false
      register: ps_cmd

The above playbook I want to run on multiple hosts and collect output in one single file.

I am new to stack overflow, somehow my playbook was printed in one liner, it will be a yml file.

According your description and the information given here you are going to (re-)implement functionality which is already there out-of-box, Custom Facts. After that, Writing ansible_facts to a file from a playbook is possible.

Despite of that, writing facts into one single file on the Control Node, creating reports on the Control Node about Remote Systems is answered already several times here on SO tag [ansible].

You can run the playbook.yml below and pipe it through grep into a file:
ansible-playbook playbook.yml|grep running > report.txt

- name: To check status of backups
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: "Check backup service"
      shell: |
         if ps -ef | grep 'netbackup' | grep -v grep > /dev/null; then
           echo "$(hostname) backup service running"
         else
           echo "$(hostname) backup service not running"
         fi
      changed_when: false
      register: ps_cmd

    - name: "Results"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ps_cmd.stdout_lines }}"

